# How do I recreate the lighting setup from my reference image in Blender?

Tags: rendering, lighting

I'm working on a project and I need to render this object in blender, but I can't figure out how to make a similar lighting setup to my reference image.

[image: Reference Image]

Mainly I want to get it so that both sides of the model have the large shadows, but nothing I've tried has been working - only one side has a small shadow.

[image: My project]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 7):

I think the shape of the pouch determines how the "shadow" looks like. Here is the setup I have tried. One strong light from front that lights up the straight front facing area of the pouch. This way the sides receive less light so they look darker. And one light from top to light the backdrop a bit, but it does not affect the pouch much. [image: light-setup]

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend HDRI lighting, specifically *studio style*. The HDRI image I used in the example below is in the blender folder at `../3.2/datafiles/studiolights/world/studio.exr`. As you can see from the image, the lighting works best when rotated 125 degrees on the Z-axis (provided the "width" of your object runs across the Y axis - if not rotate to your needs). In the image below, I also removed the image part of the HDRI and only used the lighting by mixing the image with a normal background using the *Is Camera Ray* output of a *Light Path* node as a mix factor.

[image: Studio]

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that what you are seeing on that reference image are shadows. I believe they are reflections from the shiny material of the pouch.

I would make the pouch reflective, but not glossy (high amount of diffusion) and have an environment with a brighter region behind the camera, and darker regions to the sides.